# How do I share reference PostgreSQL tables between databases?

Tags: postgresql

The system I'm designing has a set of reference tables that rarely have to be updated. New databases will be constantly started to process files that will have to query that information.

What's the best arrangement for coordinating communication between that set of information and the work database? I certainly don't want to duplicate that set of reference information in every new work database. The work databases will likely be deleted once their work is completed.

Comment: foreign data wrappers, dblink, copy from/to, etc

Comment: foreign data wrappers or logical replication.